# List<String> to List<Object>

Tags: list, flutter, charts

I want to convert a List of type String to a list of type ChartData, cause I'm creating a graph and the data (x,y) is saved on Firestore as string, so i converted the string to a List using split and now I have to convert this List of String to List of ChartData, I'm using Sync Fusion Chart. How can I do that? I tried using

```
 List<ChartData> b = strarray.map((e) => ChartData(5,1)).toList();
```

But i can't use it because When i try to use ChartData() it asks me to give the x and y.

The code: ´

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:mood3/telas/animacao.dart';
import 'package:ntp/ntp.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import '../model/GraphMood.dart';


class Graph extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<Graph> createState() => _GraphState();
}




class _GraphState extends State<Graph> {

  TooltipBehavior? _tooltipBehavior;
  DateTime ntpTime = DateTime.now();
String testefinal = '';
  _loadNTPTime() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    setState(() async {
      ntpTime = await NTP.now();
    });
  }
  Future _recuperarNome() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth2 = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user = auth2.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await db.collection('usuarios')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get();
    Map<String, dynamic> dss = ds.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    setState((){
      testefinal = dss["moodGraph"];
    });
  }

  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  initState(){
    _recuperarNome();
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
    super.initState();
    _loadNTPTime();
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ChartData> convert(String input) {
      List<ChartData> output;
      try {
        print(json);
        output = json.decode(input);
        return output;
      } catch (err) {
        print(err);
        return [ChartData(0, 0)];
      }
    }


   //List<ChartData> testim = testefinal.split(',');
    final List<ChartData> list1 = convert(testefinal);
    print(list1);
    //List<String> strs = <String>[testefinal];
    List<ChartData> dynamicValues = List<ChartData>.from(list1 as List);
    //print(strs.runtimeType);
   // List<int> numbers = strs.map(int.parse).toList();
   // print(numbers.runtimeType);
   // print(numbers);
    print(dynamicValues);
    List<String> strarray = testefinal.split(" ");
    print(strarray);
    List<ChartData> b = strarray.map((e) => ChartData(5,1)).toList();
   // List<ChartData> stringList = (jsonDecode(testefinal) as List<ChartData>).cast<ChartData>();
    //print("teste1 " + stringList.toString());
    final List<ChartData> chartData = b;



    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(

                    primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                    // Chart title
                    title: ChartTitle(text: 'Mood Chart'),
                    // Enable legend
                    legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
                    // Enable tooltip
                    tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,

                    series: <ChartSeries>[
                      // Renders line chart
                      LineSeries<ChartData, int>(
                          dataSource: chartData,
                          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x.toInt(),
                          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y
                      )
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
  final double x;
  final double y;
}
```

Basically, if i try to use the value " e " of the map on ChartData(x,y)
   `List<ChartData> b = strarray.map((e) => ChartData(5,1) <---- here ).toList();`  it says Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 1 given. So i can't use the map here. And if i try to add the List of Strings to the list List chartData = [] it says Error: A value of type 'List String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List ChartData'. So i'm thinking on add the List of strings to the List of ChartData, or convert the list of strings to list of chartData, but i don't know how to do that

Comment: Can you share the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

My Implementation For Chart you can have some idea on this :

```
class DepartmentSummary extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LeavePageState createState() => _LeavePageState();
}

class _LeavePageState extends State<DepartmentSummary> {
  late List<LeaveData> _leaveData;
  late TooltipBehavior _tooltipBehavior;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
    _leaveData = getLeavedData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
        child: SfCircularChart(
          title: ChartTitle(
              text: "Department Summary",
              textStyle:
                  TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.textColor, fontSize: 10.0)),
          tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
          legend: Legend(
              isVisible: false, overflowMode: LegendItemOverflowMode.wrap),
          series: <CircularSeries>[
            DoughnutSeries<LeaveData, String>(
                explodeIndex: 5,
                pointColorMapper: (LeaveData data, _) => data.color,
                explode: true,
                dataSource: _leaveData,
                xValueMapper: (LeaveData data, _) => data.month,
                yValueMapper: (LeaveData data, _) => data.leave,
                dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
                enableTooltip: true)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<LeaveData> getLeavedData() {
  final List<LeaveData> leaveData = [
    LeaveData("January", 10, Colors.blueAccent.shade100),
    LeaveData("February", 2, Colors.green.shade100),
    LeaveData("March", 8, Colors.blue.shade100),
    LeaveData("April", 5, Colors.indigo.shade100),
    LeaveData("May", 7, Colors.amber.shade100),
    LeaveData("June", 18, Colors.red.shade100)
  ];
  return leaveData;
}

class LeaveData {
  final String month;
  final int leave;
  Color color;
  LeaveData(this.month, this.leave, this.color);
}
```

Comment: How do you add new values to your chart? Like, if you have new information coming all the time and you have to add this information to the graph, like i'm creating something that you add a new x,y all the time and i can't add this manually. I'm using firestore to save this data and then i'm getting this data to a list that i want to set on the graph

Comment: you can use Getx and observe the changes in the list all the time . use Obx(()=> )

Comment: I'm so sorry about this, but i'm new to coding, i don't know how to do that, do you have an example that i can study and learn?

Comment: In this case, there will not have changes, only new values